# How to filter out object in options in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have  determine the cheapest, best and fastest rate in the object based on the factors below:

- cheapest is determined by `netfee` having the least value
- fastest is determined by `speed` having the least days
- best is determined by `amount` having the highest value

But what if the fastest speeds are the same? Then on what factor should depend on without conflicting other two? If for example the 'fastest' is determined by using `speed` having less days && `amount` having the highest value, it conflicts the `best` resulting best and fastest are same

I need to know on what factor should depend on when speed is same for all

```js
var obj = [{
  id: "sample1",
  netfee: 10,
  speed: "1days",
  amount: "100",
  rate: "0.5",
  netamount: "50"
}, {
  id: "sample2",
  netfee: 6,
  speed: "1days",
  amount: "200",
  rate: "0.1",
  netamount: "20"
}, {
  id: "sample3",
  netfee: 4,
  speed: "3days",
  amount: "500",
  rate: "0.2",
  netamount: "100"
}];

var cheapest = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc.netfee < cur.netfee ? acc : cur)).id,
  fastest = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => (parseInt(acc.speed, 10) < parseInt(cur.speed, 10) ? acc : cur)).id,
  best = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => (Number(acc.amount) > Number(cur.amount) ? acc : cur)).id;

console.log("cheapest =", cheapest)
console.log("fastest  =", fastest)
console.log("best     =", best)
```

Comment: They sounds like questions that only your tutor can advise you on.

Comment: Why not just use their original index as factor?

Comment: There isn't a technical answer for this.  It will depend on the requirements.  If you're trying to find "fastest" then only speed will be relevant, if two have the same speed then they are *both* the fastest by definition - you can't add another factor unless it's related to speed.  And that includes the random order they were originally generated in - using the order they were generated in would give you which was "fastest first" - which is just confusing.